# Not work with the enclosure in RSS Feed

Tags: php, rss

I have a problem with the enclosure and I can not read the images from various websites including enclosure

The code I use is:

```
<?php
  $doc = new DOMDocument();
  $doc->load('http://www.example.com/feed/rss1.rss');
  $arrFeeds = array();
  $cnt=0;
  foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
      if($cnt == 5 ) {
       break;
     } 
    $itemRSS = array ( 
      'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
      'desc' => $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue,
      'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
      'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue,
      'enclosure' => $node->getElementsByTagName('enclosure')->item(0)->nodeValue
      );
      $cnt++;
?>

<h2><a href="<?php echo $itemRSS['link']; ?>"><?php echo $itemRSS['title']; ?></a></h2>
<p><?php echo $itemRSS['desc']; ?></p>
<img src="<?php echo $itemRSS['enclosure']; ?>">
<?php  } ?>
```

Can you tell me where I'm wrong?
Thanks :)

Comment: What is the exact error? And please share your feed markup with us.

Comment: Can you try to echo $itemRSS['enclosure'] without the <img> tag?

Answer (score 3):

The enclosure tag doesn't contain the url as a value, it's in a 'url' attribute. Try something like this instead:

```
 'enclosure' => $node->getElementsByTagName('enclosure')->item(0)->getAttribute('url')
```

Comment: In case there is no enclosure and has <![CDATA how we can turn to read in accordance with the above code?